# Cosine Similarity of Vectors, with < O(n^2) complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, information-retrieval

Having looked around this site for similar issues, I found this: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/ and this: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/09/ir-math-with-java-similarity-measures.html

However, it seems these run in O(n^2). I've been doing some document clustering and noticed this level of complexity wasn't feasible when dealing with even small document sets. Given, for the dot product, we only need the vector terms contained in both vectors it should be possible to put the vectors in a tree and thus compute the dot product with n log n complexity, where n is the lowest number of unique terms in 1 of the 2 documents.

Am I missing something? Is there a java library which does this?

thanks

Comment: You're not going to have a lot of luck expecting people to read both those pages.  Perhaps you could explain your problem more clearly - why are you multiplying vectors (and what do you mean, O(n^2)?  Computing the dot-product of two n-dimensional vectors is trivially O(n), I highly doubt any vector package could screw up that badly)

Comment: He is computing dot product for every *pair* of documents. That makes it quadratically complex.

Comment: BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft, this problem is about multiplying very large-dimensional but very sparse vectors; and n is not dimension but count of non-zero elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the vector elements in a hashtable, lookup is only log n anyway, no? Loop over all keys in the smaller document and see if they exist in the larger one..?

Comment: Any class you would recommend? I figure this one is pretty good, if memory is an issue: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Amemoryefficienthashmap.htm

Comment: Wow can't judge this so quickly, but you can always go with a normal java.util.HashMap to begin with. 

Btw since you're saying it's an effect of document collection size: If you compare each document to each document, you have another quadratic term (now in the number of documents) wrapped around the (n*log n) term. For me, this part has often been far more problematic than the actual cosine computation. Could this be the case for you as well?

Comment: I do trimming on the cluster set to get the comparison down to a constant, but for something like GAHC you're completely correct, you have an n^2 problem, where n is the number of clusters to be compared.

Answer (score 2):

Hashmap is good, but it might take a lot of memory.

If your vectors are stored as key-value pairs sorted by key then vector multiplication can be done in O(n): you just have to iterate in parallel over both vectors (the same iteration is used e.g. in merge sort algorithm). The pseudocode for multiplication:

```
i = 0
j = 0
result = 0
while i < length(vec1) && j < length(vec2):
  if vec1[i].key == vec2[j].key:
    result = result + vec1[i].value * vec2[j].value
  else if vec1[i].key < vec2[j].key:
    i = i + 1
  else
    j = j + 1
```

Comment: I like this idea, thanks. Is there a java library which uses this principle?

Comment: I don't know; but lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) might contain such algorithm.

Comment: Thanks dmitry-vk, it seems a sorted map would probably be best: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on using cosine similarity as a way of finding clusters of similar documents, you may want to consider looking into [locality-sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), a hash-based approach that was designed specifically with this in mind. Intuitively, LSH hashes the vectors in a way that with high probability places similar elements into the same bucket and distant elements into different buckets. There are LSH schemes that use cosine similarity as their underlying distance, so to find clusters you use LSH to drop things into buckets and then only compute the pairwise distances of elements in the same bucket. In the worst case this will be quadratic (if everything falls in the same bucket), but it's much more likely that you'll have a significant dropoff in work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to recommend limited items, for example m items, to every item in a set with size of n, the complexity need not to be n^2, but m*n. Since m is a constant, the complexity is linear.

You can check with the project simbase https://github.com/guokr/simbase , it is a vector similarity nosql database.

Simbase use below concepts:

- Vector set: a set of vectors
- Basis: the basis for vectors, vectors in one vector set have same basis
- Recommendation: a one-direction binary relationship between two vector sets which have the same basis